# Aspxmemo -> Is it possible to set the text color and boldness via the clientside?

Tags: devexpress, client-side

I am using a devexpress control on my page and basically everything is on the clientside.  I have been able to use the setText in order to set the text values in the control, but I have been unable to figure out how to set the color and boldness of the text via the clientside.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I checked the clientside page on devExpress's website, but I didn't see anything there.

[AspxMemo Clientside](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientMemoMembersTopicAll)

Thoughts, suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the following code:

```
function SetMemoProperties() {
        var tArea = memo.GetInputElement();
        tArea.style.color = "red";
        tArea.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
```

Comment: Awesome I marking as answer but if that works that is amazing thanks.